# Extract the first(Top) result from a list in descending order from SQL to Spring

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT 1 b.updateDate FROM DemandUnit b ORDER BY b.updateDate DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
LocalDateTime findTopByOrderByUpdateDateDesc();
```

This is my query to return the most recent update date from a table. 
Following error occurs:

```
{"timestamp": "2020-03-20T18:31:19.094+0000",
 "status": 500,
 "error": "Internal Server Error",
 "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
 "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
        org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
 "path": "/api/batch/demand/update/check"}
```

any hint what might causing it?

Comment: I doubt the `1` needs to be in your query. Also is `DemandUnit` your table name or entity name? You are using a native sql query so it should refer to your table NOT your entity.

Comment: Demandunit is the entity name. I have changed it to table name. Remove the 1. still the same error showing.

Comment: The query should also be using column names and not entity field names, because as mentioned before you wanted a native sql query.

Comment: column name is update_date. would it be : SELECT 1 b.update_date FROM DemandUnit b ORDER BY b.update_date DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: after changing to the top query I got "Execution failed for task ':service:compileQuerydslJava'." build error.

Comment: Again no. You are writing SQL` not JPQL. So must write a query containing dB references NOT entity references. Also the 1 is wrong.

Comment: original table name: demand_stage_raw: i have changed my query to : "@Query(value = "SELECT TOP b.update_date FROM demand_stage_raw b ORDER BY b.update_date DESC ", nativeQuery = true)"  ______ same error persists.

Comment: Remove top that isn’t valid sql`. I strongly suggest, a read of how sql works instead of trial and error.

Comment: Remoned the top. Got a different error: "message": "result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements", my function : LocalDateTime findTopByOrderByUpdateDateDesc() is expected to return the most updated time.

Comment: Taking your suggestion. Stopped trying and testing.

Comment: Again read how sql works. You need a limiting part in your query. How to write that depends on your database.